# How to predict a good resonance structure?

Tags: resonance

[image]

I have to draw curved arrows to convert the above molecule to its resonance structure but I'm not entirely sure how. I believe the sulfur atom has one lone pair and the oxygen atom has 2 lone pairs. But how would I be able to predict the location of the curved arrows?

I took a look at their formal charge and both seem to be 0.

Comment: Well, major resonance structures rarely involve tetrahedral carbons, so we can probably rule out any electron movement in the S-C single bonds. What do you think about the electron distribution in the S=O double bond?

Comment: As another hint: Add *all* the electron pairs into the structure, it might give you an idea. (Also, the resonance structure you have drawn is no longer considered major ;))

Comment: oxygen is more electronegative so would a pi bond go to the oxygen atom and make that O-?

Comment: Yes, but those would be only formal charges reflecting it's single dative bond